# Hg acl extension: prevent push based on branch and file name

Tags: mercurial, acl

Using the [ACL](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension) extension of hg, I managed to prevent users to push on some branches (see `[acl.deny.branches]`) or some files (see `[acl.deny], [acl.allow]`).
However I would like to be able to mix both control. Here is an example:

- we have two users, alice and bob
- the repo is made of two files A and B
- we have two branches, default and wip
- alice should have RW access to both branches, on both A and B
- bob should have RW access to A and B on the wip branch, but should have only
  RW access to A on the default branch. bob must not be able to push a commit which modifies B on the default branch.

In this example, the access rights for bob are a mix of branch and file rules. Is it possible ?